# To disable SSL for changing https to http without changing any other communication which happens over SSL

Tags: browser

This might be silly question as I am very new to this. Please help me knowing the details:

I have only below information for a application:

1) Application is accessed using https through browser

2) Application talks to LDAP over SSL connection for authentication purpose

Now, my question is, if there would be some relation between SSL used by https and the SSL which application is using to communicate with LDAP?

Can we disable SSL so that application is accessed using http but the communication between application and LDAP is still over SSL?

There is requirement to change https to http because of some compatibility issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, my question is, if there would be some relation between SSL used
>   by https and the SSL which application is using to communicate with
>   LDAP?

No, those are 2 different connections. In the first case the client is the browser and the server is your application and in the second case the client is your application and the server is LDAP.

> Can we disable SSL so that application is accessed using http but the
>   communication between application and LDAP is still over SSL?

Yes, absolutely. Of course that would mean that the users passwords will be sent as cleartext between their browsers and your application. Depending on your scenario this could be acceptable but for a publicly facing website I would rather say that this is bad practice.